# I want to design a jTable in swing with colspan and rowspan facility without any data value

Tags: java, swing, jtable, custom-component, jtableheader

I have already used GroupableTableHeaderExample but without data it's doesn't work. Here Is my code.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package view;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class ColumnGroup {

    protected TableCellRenderer renderer;
    protected Vector v;
    protected String text;
    protected int margin = 0;

    public ColumnGroup(String text) {
        this(null, text);
    }

    public ColumnGroup(TableCellRenderer renderer, String text) {
        if (renderer == null) {
            this.renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
                public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                    JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
                    if (header != null) {
                        setForeground(header.getForeground());
                        setBackground(header.getBackground());
                        setFont(header.getFont());
                    }
                    setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                    setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
                    setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
                    return this;
                }
            };
        } else {
            this.renderer = renderer;
        }
        this.text = text;
        v = new Vector();
    }

    /**
     * @param obj TableColumn or ColumnGroup
     */
    public void add(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return;
        }
        v.addElement(obj);
    }

    /**
     * @param c TableColumn
     * @param v ColumnGroups
     */
    public Vector getColumnGroups(TableColumn c, Vector g) {
        g.addElement(this);
        if (v.contains(c)) {
            return g;
        }
        Enumeration e = v.elements();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object obj = e.nextElement();
            if (obj instanceof ColumnGroup) {
                Vector groups =
                        (Vector) ((ColumnGroup) obj).getColumnGroups(c, (Vector) g.clone());
                if (groups != null) {
                    return groups;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public TableCellRenderer getHeaderRenderer() {
        return renderer;
    }

    public void setHeaderRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer) {
        if (renderer != null) {
            this.renderer = renderer;
        }
    }

    public Object getHeaderValue() {
        return text;
    }

    public Dimension getSize(JTable table) {
        Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, getHeaderValue(), false, false, -1, -1);
        int height = comp.getPreferredSize().height;
        int width = 0;
        Enumeration e = v.elements();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object obj = e.nextElement();
            if (obj instanceof TableColumn) {
                TableColumn aColumn = (TableColumn) obj;
                width += aColumn.getWidth();
                width += margin;
            } else {
                width += ((ColumnGroup) obj).getSize(table).width;
            }
        }
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    public void setColumnMargin(int margin) {
        this.margin = margin;
        Enumeration e = v.elements();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object obj = e.nextElement();
            if (obj instanceof ColumnGroup) {
                ((ColumnGroup) obj).setColumnMargin(margin);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another class is GroupableTableHeaderUI.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package view;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class GroupableTableHeaderUI extends BasicTableHeaderUI {

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {

        Rectangle clipBounds = g.getClipBounds();
        if (header.getColumnModel() == null) {
            return;
        }
        ((GroupableTableHeader) header).setColumnMargin();
        int column = 0;
        Dimension size = header.getSize();
        Rectangle cellRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
        int columnMargin = header.getColumnModel().getColumnMargin();

        Enumeration enumeration = header.getColumnModel().getColumns();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            cellRect.height = size.height;
            cellRect.y = 0;
            TableColumn aColumn = (TableColumn) enumeration.nextElement();
            Enumeration cGroups = ((GroupableTableHeader) header).getColumnGroups(aColumn);
            if (cGroups != null) {
                int groupHeight = 0;
                while (cGroups.hasMoreElements()) {
                    ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup) cGroups.nextElement();
                    Rectangle groupRect = (Rectangle) h.get(cGroup);
                    if (groupRect == null) {
                        groupRect = new Rectangle(cellRect);
                        Dimension d = cGroup.getSize(header.getTable());
                        groupRect.width = d.width;
                        groupRect.height = d.height;
                        h.put(cGroup, groupRect);
                    }
                    paintCell(g, groupRect, cGroup);
                    groupHeight += groupRect.height;
                    cellRect.height = size.height - groupHeight;
                    cellRect.y = groupHeight;
                }
            }
            cellRect.width = aColumn.getWidth() + columnMargin;
            if (cellRect.intersects(clipBounds)) {
                paintCell(g, cellRect, column);
            }
            cellRect.x += cellRect.width;
            column++;
        }
    }

    private void paintCell(Graphics g, Rectangle cellRect, int columnIndex) {
        TableColumn aColumn = header.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex);
        TableCellRenderer renderer = aColumn.getHeaderRenderer();
        //revised by Java2s.com
        renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                JLabel header = new JLabel();
                header.setForeground(table.getTableHeader().getForeground());
                header.setBackground(table.getTableHeader().getBackground());
                header.setFont(table.getTableHeader().getFont());

                header.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                header.setText(value.toString());
                header.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
                return header;
            }
        };
        Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                header.getTable(), aColumn.getHeaderValue(), false, false, -1, columnIndex);

        c.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("control"));

        rendererPane.add(c);
        rendererPane.paintComponent(g, c, header, cellRect.x, cellRect.y,
                cellRect.width, cellRect.height, true);
    }

    private void paintCell(Graphics g, Rectangle cellRect, ColumnGroup cGroup) {
        TableCellRenderer renderer = cGroup.getHeaderRenderer();
        //revised by Java2s.com
        // if(renderer == null){
//      return ;
        //    }

        Component component = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                header.getTable(), cGroup.getHeaderValue(), false, false, -1, -1);
        rendererPane.add(component);
        rendererPane.paintComponent(g, component, header, cellRect.x, cellRect.y,
                cellRect.width, cellRect.height, true);
    }

    private int getHeaderHeight() {
        int height = 0;
        TableColumnModel columnModel = header.getColumnModel();
        for (int column = 0; column < columnModel.getColumnCount(); column++) {
            TableColumn aColumn = columnModel.getColumn(column);
            TableCellRenderer renderer = aColumn.getHeaderRenderer();
            //revised by Java2s.com
            if (renderer == null) {
                return 60;
            }

            Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    header.getTable(), aColumn.getHeaderValue(), false, false, -1, column);
            int cHeight = comp.getPreferredSize().height;
            Enumeration e = ((GroupableTableHeader) header).getColumnGroups(aColumn);
            if (e != null) {
                while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                    ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup) e.nextElement();
                    cHeight += cGroup.getSize(header.getTable()).height;
                }
            }
            height = Math.max(height, cHeight);
        }
        return height;
    }

    private Dimension createHeaderSize(long width) {
        TableColumnModel columnModel = header.getColumnModel();
        width += columnModel.getColumnMargin() * columnModel.getColumnCount();
        if (width > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            width = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        return new Dimension((int) width, getHeaderHeight());
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
        long width = 0;
        Enumeration enumeration = header.getColumnModel().getColumns();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            TableColumn aColumn = (TableColumn) enumeration.nextElement();
            width = width + aColumn.getPreferredWidth();
        }
        return createHeaderSize(width);
    }
}
```

3rd one is GroupableTableHeader.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package view;

import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class GroupableTableHeader extends JTableHeader {

    private static final String uiClassID = "GroupableTableHeaderUI";
    protected Vector columnGroups = null;

    public GroupableTableHeader(TableColumnModel model) {
        super(model);
        setUI(new GroupableTableHeaderUI());
        setReorderingAllowed(false);
    }

    public void updateUI() {
        setUI(new GroupableTableHeaderUI());
    }

    public void setReorderingAllowed(boolean b) {
        reorderingAllowed = false;
    }

    public void addColumnGroup(ColumnGroup g) {
        if (columnGroups == null) {
            columnGroups = new Vector();
        }
        columnGroups.addElement(g);
    }

    public Enumeration getColumnGroups(TableColumn col) {
        if (columnGroups == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Enumeration e = columnGroups.elements();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup) e.nextElement();
            Vector v_ret = (Vector) cGroup.getColumnGroups(col, new Vector());
            if (v_ret != null) {
                return v_ret.elements();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setColumnMargin() {
        if (columnGroups == null) {
            return;
        }
        int columnMargin = getColumnModel().getColumnMargin();
        Enumeration e = columnGroups.elements();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup) e.nextElement();
            cGroup.setColumnMargin(columnMargin);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my code in MainFrame.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package view;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    MainFrame() {
        super("Groupable Header Example");

//        DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
//        dm.setDataVector(new Object[][]{
//            {"119", "foo", "bar", "ja", "ko", "zh"},
//            {"911", "bar", "foo", "en", "fr", "pt"}},
//                new Object[]{"SNo.", "1", "2", "Native", "2", "3"});

        JTable table = new JTable() {
            protected JTableHeader createDefaultTableHeader() {
                return new GroupableTableHeader(columnModel);
            }
        };


        TableColumnModel cm = table.getColumnModel();
        ColumnGroup g_name = new ColumnGroup("Name");
        g_name.add(cm.getColumn(1));
        g_name.add(cm.getColumn(2));
        ColumnGroup g_lang = new ColumnGroup("Language");
        g_lang.add(cm.getColumn(3));
        ColumnGroup g_other = new ColumnGroup("Others");
        g_other.add(cm.getColumn(4));
        g_other.add(cm.getColumn(5));
        g_lang.add(g_other);

        GroupableTableHeader header = (GroupableTableHeader) table.getTableHeader();
        header.addColumnGroup(g_name);
        header.addColumnGroup(g_lang);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scroll);
        setSize(400, 120);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But It doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly **doesn't work**? and What's your question?

Comment: Since you've copied the code from somewhere of the internet, yes, I'm familiar with this code, you should beware that to does not support setting the row sorting by clicking the column, nor does it support dragging columns to change there order...and the annoying part, the column size cursor is visible in the column group header :P

Comment: Yes In the very beginning conveying that I have used this code from somewhere else. What I am trying to edit the code to solve my purpose.Now the main issue is in MainFrame class an object of  DefaultTableModel is created by which a set of data is setting overthere but I want to table without any data and only with the header.Here should also have the facility user can give input in the table.